# Should I add a field like MarkedAsDeleted to my table?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application with SQL Server. I would like to know what will be a good practice for record deletion operations. I mean, when an item is deleted via web application, I would like to mark it as deleted, and then from an admin console, I will purge them if needed.

Is this a good practice? Should I use or avoid?

Thank you.

Comment: Or you can fill in an invalid value in one of the fields to save up space. The UI can display the record as invalid if that field has an invalid value. E.g age = -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach if you have no issues with storage space.  Typically, we will use this pattern if the object being deleted is tied to other object (for instance, if you were tracking changes by user id, then you would not want to delete the user because you would not be able to pull info for that user later on).  Simply mark a bit field showing the record has been deleted and filter those out when you query.

Again, it really depends on what makes sense for you and your application.  Will you ever need this object again?  Is it tied to other items in the database?  Do you want to offer the user the option to 'undelete'?  If the answer to any of those questions is yes, then you should probably keep the record.  If the answer to all of those is no, then I would ask, why would you not just delete the record at the time it was requested?